# Material reacting to UV for testing

Tags: material-science

For testing purpose, I'd need a material that could change of color after being exposed to UV for a period of time (let's say, few minutes).

Do you know if such a material exists or is it better to use a device to measure the UV at a certain location?

Thanks in advance for you answers and have a great day!

Adrien

Comment: Try to use [Photochromic lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photochromic_lens)

Comment: I'm sure they do since UV degrades materials and there are UV cure materials as well (your dentist uses them). But you never said how strong this UV source is.

Comment: Are trying to measure the UV _[dose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbed_dose)_ that is received by some test subject? If so, then a Google search for "UV dosimeter" might get you some useful info.

Comment: It is more to make sure that the UV went through a given material so we need to detect it after the given material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is, it is called a *UV dosimetry tag* which comes in sheets divided up into individual squares with self-adhesive backing. You peel one off, stick it on the material, and expose it to UV light. The tags start off pale yellow and gradually turn green then dark blue as they accumulate exposure. You compare the color of the spent tag against a chart prepared in advance consisting of a bunch of tags exposed to known doses and find the match.